# Is there a PHP editor that could do intellisense of your own variables?

Tags: php, macos, editor

Which PHP editor ( for MAC OS/X ) would you recommend free/premium that would not only allow you to do all the basic jazz such as auto-ftp, intellisense, syntax highlighting, and of course step-thru debugging BUT ALSO the auto-complete of your own variables?

so, if you do;

```
$my_name = "ABC";
```

and later on down the page, when you type `$my_n`, you get the  `"ame"` is auto suggested.

Comment: all decent editors should be able to do that, even on mac.

Comment: Netbeans does it, and I am pretty sure @Elzo Valugi is right that all decent ones do it.

Comment: Unfortunately this falls into the shopping category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure most modern IDEs support this. I'm using [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/), and can confirm it has the feature you described.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IDE such as [Eclipse for Mac](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), it's free, open-source, and it has autocomplete. I use it for PHP development and it has everything I need.

However, **most IDE also have autocomplete**, it's up to you to compare them and see which one fits you the best.

Comment: I believe Eclipse requires you to install the PDT plugin, at least on windows it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
[The PHP IDE of Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html)
it does exactly what you're asking for.